# each character is printing in newline

Tags: python

I'm solving a `hackerrank` problem where I can modify and write function code only but I can't modify drivers code (taking input and printing output). I wrote the code but it prints each character of a string in a new line as output. **the problem is** : to check balanced parenthesis and print `"YES"` or `"NO"` as output. How can I return the word where I can only modify the function code .

```
def braces(values):

  open_tup = tuple('({[') 
  close_tup = tuple(')}]') 
  map = dict(zip(open_tup, close_tup)) 
  queue = [] 

  for i in values: 
    if i in open_tup: 
        queue.append(map[i]) 
    elif i in close_tup: 
        if not queue or i != queue.pop(): 
            return "NO"
  return "YES"


if __name__ == '__main__':
fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

values_count = int(input())

values = []

for _ in range(values_count):
    values_item = input()
    values.append(values_item)

res = braces(values)

fptr.write('\n'.join(res))
fptr.write('\n')

fptr.close()

 output:
    Y
    E
    S
```

Comment: that I can't change(not accessible). whatever I want to do I can do only in function code only.

Comment: So you are saying you can't modify this line: `fptr.write('\n'.join(res))`?

Comment: I don't know why hackerank doesn't allow users to modify that part of code. this happened many times.

Comment: Are you sure that they don't ask to check the balanced braces for each input separately? If that's the case, you should return a list of YES/NO answers

Comment: they asked separate output for each test case

Answer (score 1):

`return ["YES"]` It feels like collage :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `join` call.
Instead of

```
fptr.write('\n'.join(res))
```

you need to write

```
fptr.write(''.join(res))
```

Additionally, consider using `with` instead:

```
with open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w') as fptr:
    fptr.write(''.join(res))
```

Comment: @RafalS: But this is really weird. I wonder if this comes from the fact that OP does not seem to be a native speaker.

Comment: Sounds like a typical collage task :D